# Is it possible to change the active user for a PostgreSQL connection?

Tags: database, postgresql, database-connection

Given a connection to the PostgreSQL database for user 'Alice', is there a statement that could be executed to switch to user 'Bob'?

Motivation: Looking to avoid having separate pools for each user (i.e. re-use a connection that was previously used by another user).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do `set role bob;`, but for that to work alice must have been granted bob.  Note that a non-cooperating user could just set the role back to alice again if they wanted to.

Comment: thank you -- someone I know had suggested that but I missed some subtly in the docs.

Answer (score 0):

In PgAdmin open part Login/Group roles.
Right click and in opened window enter new user, set permission and defined password.
After refresh you will see e.g. Alice in Login/Group roles.
After that open database with logged user.
Click on something like mondial/postgres@PostgresSQL (db/user@server) and choose new connection.
Chose which db wish to use and user wich will be connected on db.

After that you will have mondial/Alice@PostgresSQL